# Swap drives between Dell D630 and D820

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, dell-latitude

I've a Dell Latitude D630 running WinXP with the Intel integrated graphics. I believe the display is failing on this - or something certainly is. I also have a D820 with the nVidia graphics, currently running Vista.

I would like to put the hard-drive from the faulty D630 directly into the D820 - since they are so similar I figured this might be possible? Is it likely to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may work.  I have done this between a 620 and 820 and there were minimal issues.  A quick install of drivers addressed issues. As I have used a GHOST image from 820 and 830 systems almost interchangably, It should be possible once drivers are addressed.

Video is a common issue as is wireless and wired ethernet. [Enter the service tag](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs) from the "new" laptop and get all drivers on a CD or USB drive so you can update once the swap is done.